# Getting input fields from Array List in React Js

Tags: javascript

I have fetch array from API where input fields are mentioned, below is example:

```
customerAttribute: Array(11)
0: {attributeId: 1, attributeName: "FirstName", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false}
1: {attributeId: 2, attributeName: "LastName", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false}
2: {attributeId: 3, attributeName: "DateOfBirth", attributeType: "Date", isMandatory: false}
3: {attributeId: 4, attributeName: "Email Address", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false}
4: {attributeId: 5, attributeName: "Mobile Number", attributeType: "Number", isMandatory: false}
5: {attributeId: 6, attributeName: "Address Line 1", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false}
6: {attributeId: 7, attributeName: "Address Line 2", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false}
7: {attributeId: 8, attributeName: "City", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false}
```

Now I have already const an where default fields are mentioned:

```
 const ABC = [
    { ...firstName, order: 1 },
    { ...lastName, order: 2 },
    { ...mobileNumber, order: 3 },
    { ...email, order: 4 },
    { ...address1, order: 5 },
    { ...address2, order: 6 },
    { ...city, order: 7 },
 ]
```

I wanted to display only field which is available in array list of CustomerAttribute

Can anyone suggest what can I Do..??

Comment: the above is the response of the API?

Comment: customerAttributes is response of API.

Comment: it must in the array !!! like customer customerAttribute:[
 {attributeId: 1, attributeName: "FirstName", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false}]

Comment: yes.. I have paste the response from console log

Answer (score 0):

First of all response is always in JSON and it will be in array, it must be like and below is the for loop which will give you the required values you want like attributeID, attributeName

```
var  customerAttribute =
[ {attributeId: 1, attributeName: "FirstName", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false},
 {attributeId: 2, attributeName: "LastName", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false},
 {attributeId: 3, attributeName: "DateOfBirth", attributeType: "Date", isMandatory: false},
 {attributeId: 4, attributeName: "Email Address", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false},
 {attributeId: 5, attributeName: "Mobile Number", attributeType: "Number", isMandatory: false},
 {attributeId: 6, attributeName: "Address Line 1", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false},
 {attributeId: 7, attributeName: "Address Line 2", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false},
 {attributeId: 8, attributeName: "City", attributeType: "String", isMandatory: false}]


    for (let index = 0; index < customerAttribute.length; index++) {

        console.log(customerAttribute[index].attributeId)
        console.log(customerAttribute[index].attributeName)

    }
```

Comment: this is JSON, i need it in React Js